# ExcelDNA refresh data when clicking on ENTER Key

Tags: excel, plugins, excel-dna

I'm using exceldna library to build an excel plugin. the problem is that when i type my function let say "=Add(A1;B1)", everything works fine, but when i edit the function (entring something in the cell), the data don't refresh. so i have to go to the FX bar and edit/validate the function by typing "ENTER"
is there any solution to validate the function directly on the cell ?

Comment: Not sure if it's because of excel-dna, but have you accidentally turned calculation to manual? In VBA you can run `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the default behavior of a regular Excel function implemented via Excel-DNA.

It's possible that Excel calculation mode is setup to manual (and therefore the formulas are not being recalculated automatically), or maybe you have some caching mechanism on your function that is returning the previous value.

> [How Excel determines the current mode of calculation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214395/how-excel-determines-the-current-mode-of-calculation)